# Calling a stored procedure on mysql from jsp does not update my database table

Tags: mysql, jsp, stored-procedures, jdbc

I'm writing this code for calling stored procedure on mysql database from my jsp using callable interface to register a customer, here's the stored procedure code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `register_customer`(in firstname varchar(45),
in lastname varchar(45),in contactnumber varchar(45),in username varchar(100),
in pass varchar(45),in emailid varchar(45),in gender varchar(45) )
BEGIN
insert into customers (First_Name,Last_Name,Contact_Number,User_Name,Password,Email_Id,Gender)
 values(firstname,lastname,contactnumber,username,pass,emailid,gender);
END
```

and here is the java code for calling stored procedure

```
 <body>
    <h1>Hello Account holder</h1>
    <%!
    public class SignUp{
    String firstname;
    String secondname;
    String Gender;
    String emailid;
    String password;
    String rpassword;
    //connection variables
    PreparedStatement insert=null;
    CallableStatement procstate=null;
    Connection connection=null;
    String URL=null;
    String server_user=null;
    String server_password=null;

    int result=0;
    //constructor
    public SignUp()
    {
        try{
            URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onlinestore";
            server_user="root";
            server_password="Bitp0cketer";
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection(URL,server_user,server_password);
           // insert=connection.prepareStatement("Insert into customes(First_Name,Last_Name,User_Name,Password,Email_Id,Gender values('?','?','?','?','?','?'))");
            procstate=connection.prepareCall("{call register_customer(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();          
        }
    }

    public void  registeruser(String fn,String ln,String un,String pas,String emailid,String gender)
    {
       try{
           //insert=connection.prepareStatement("Insert into customers(First_Name,Last_Name,User_Name,Password,Email_Id,Gender) values('"+fn+"','"+ln+"','"+un+"','"+pas+"','"+emailid+"','"+gender+"')");

           //result=insert.executeUpdate();
           /* storedprocedure calling*/

           procstate.setString(1, fn);
           procstate.setString(2,ln);
           procstate.setString(3,un);
           procstate.setString(4,pas);
           procstate.setString(5,emailid);
           procstate.setString(6,gender);

           result =procstate.executeUpdate();
        }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }       

    }

    }

    %>
    <%
    SignUp sp=new SignUp();
    String fn;
    String ln;
    String un;
     String pas;
     String emailid;
     String gender;
     fn=request.getParameter("first");
     ln=request.getParameter("last");
     un=request.getParameter("username");
     emailid=request.getParameter("emailid");
     pas=request.getParameter("pas");
     gender=request.getParameter("Gender");
    String cpass=request.getParameter("cpass");
    sp.registeruser(fn, ln, un, pas, emailid, gender);
    %>
```

no exception is thrown, no error is generated but it doesn't insert a record in my database, i dunno why, kindly look into it and help me sorting out the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure has to be called like

```
procstate = con.prepareCall("{call register_customer(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");  
procstate.setString(1, fn);
procstate.setString(2,ln);
procstate.setString(3,un);
procstate.setString(4,pas);
procstate.setString(5,emailid);
procstate.setString(6,gender);
procstate.execute();
```

**Update :**   In your stored procedure, you have 7 parameters. But you are passing 6 arguments in your java code. `contactnumber` missing

Comment: Insert is commented out, my actual statement is procstatement, which gets executed in registeruser method.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing,kindly read registeruser method, procstate get initialized in constructor the IN parameters get set in method and that's where the procedure is given a call from, if i do it with simple preparedStatment fed with string sql query it works fine, but with stored procedure it doesn't do anything.

Comment: In your stored procedure, you have 7 arguments. But you are passing 6 values in your java code. `contactnumber` missing.  This may be the problem

Comment: Thanks for saving my life, that was the idiotic mistake i made.

Comment: Happy to help you.